# To Add Title to Anchor tag using Jquery from Resource file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add Title Attribute to Anchor Tag (from my Resource file) that is getting generated by below mentioned code.

```
var hyperlinkopen = divTitleBar.children('a');
                hyperlinkopen.removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-open ui-corner-all");
                hyperlinkopen.addClass("ui-dialog-help-layer-titlebar-open");
```

Title should be like `Title="Open"`. How can I add title to my anchor tag?

Answer (score 2):

use jquery .attr() to set any attribute.
for yours it will be 
`divTitleBar.children('a').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-open ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-dialog-help-layer-titlebar-open").attr('title','Open');`

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward, say which attribute you want to change and give it a value

```
hyperlinkopen.attr('title','open');
```

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. But now I am facing one more depended issue. I want to read this title's attribute value from my Resource file. So what should be syntax??